# Trying to install Pygame with a "not a supported wheel" error

Tags: python, pygame, pip

I am trying to install Pygame and I keep getting the error message:

> pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I am using Python version 3.5.2 64 bit on a 64-bit computer. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The message says "...not a supported wheel **on this platform**".  What is your operating system?

Comment: It is 32bit version for Windows. Do you use 32bit Python on Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an incompatible wheel file for your operating system OS/Python/other version. I think it is the `win32` part (you're on 64 bit and maybe it doesn't like that).

Go to [this website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and download the one named `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`. It matches your OS (64 bit) and your Python (3.5/64 bit) requirements perfectly.